# replace inf values with 0 in netcdf in python

Tags: python, netcdf, python-xarray

I can replace nan values in NetCDF using xarray like this:

```
hndl_nc = hndl_nc.fillna(0.0)
```

Is there a way to replace inf values with 0 as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Numpy's `isfinite` captures both `np.inf` and `np.nan`.

```
hndl_nc.where(hndl_nc.apply(np.isfinite)).fillna(0.0)
```

*Note that the next version of xarray (0.10) will allow you to specify the fill value in the `where method` directly.*

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
def replace_inf_with_zero(dataset):
    for varname in dataset.data_vars.keys():
        array = hndl_nc[varname]
        array[array == np.inf] = 0.
```